# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"conversations", :recipient_id=>2, :sender_id=>1}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a feature into my Rails app that allows users to message other users. I am running into a problem with my conversations index view. This view features a button that a user can click on to message another user ("Message Me!" button below).

```
<div class=”ui segment”>
 <h3>Mailbox</h3>
 <div class=”ui list”>
  <div class=”item”>
   <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
   <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id ||      conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
    <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
      <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
    <% else %>
      <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to recipient.username,   conversation_messages_path(conversation)%>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class=”ui segment”>
 <h3>All Users</h3>
  <div class=”ui list”>
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if user.id != current_user.id %>
     <div class=”item”>
   <%= user.username %> <%= link_to "Message me!", conversation_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id)%>
 </div>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

It seems there is a problem with the call to the conversation path, as I am getting an error saying No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"conversations", :recipient_id=>2, :sender_id=>1}, missing required keys: [:id]" for that line.
Why would it be looking for an :id key, though? This is my conversations controller

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_if_not_logged_in
    
    def index
     @users = User.all
     @conversations = Conversation.all
     end

     def create
      if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).present?
        @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
      else
        @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
      end
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end

    private

     def conversation_params
      params.require(:conversation).permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
     end
end
```

Can anybody help me figure out what is wrong? I am new to Rails. Thank you

Comment: `conversation_path` needs an `id: ..`

Comment: You have not set the route up correctly.  This: `conversation_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id)` gives two params to the path a `sender_id` param and a `recipient_id` param.  But the route is still looking for the single `id` of the object to grab and show.  If you need the route to look like this `conversation/?sender_id=1&recipient_id=2` (I just made the id's up of course) you need to set that up right now it looks like the route wants `conversation/1` and I bet if you run `rake routes` you would see it looking for that like this `conversation/:id` for the show method.